# Server to Server Payments using Braintree

Tags: braintree

I'm currently interested in using Braintree to make payments from a server using credit card credentials that I currently hold to another payment server.

[image]

Currently, the payment nonce is generated by the Braintree Client SDK when a client enter in his credit card details.

However, I want to set it up such that my server, which already contains my credit card details, will generate the payment nonce and send it to another server which accepts Braintree payment nonces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

If you already have the credit card details, you can first [create a payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/reference/request/payment-method/create#braintree-paymentmethod.create()) from those. Once you have a payment method you can treat it just like you would a nonce to [create transactions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/guides/transactions#sale).

**Just keep in mind this has additional [PCI concerns](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/reference/security/pci-compliance) with raw credit card data being present on your server.**

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.